# Remove Folder name HTACCESS and file extension?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

This is Code,which is use for removing file extension. I want to remove Directory name as well.what to add in this code.
Structure of project= airgle is a index page contains navigation pages.

now,my url is 
`localhost/demo/airgle/navigation1`
i wants  `localhost/demo/navigation1`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in `/demo/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /demo/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?! airgle/).+?)/?$ airgle/ [L,NC]
```

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL /demo/airgle/AirPurifiers was not found on this server.

Comment: What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: Is this .htaccess placed in `/demo/` directory?

Comment: please suggest me some tutorials of htaccess with php .. :)

Comment: i have one more query,i searched on google,but didn't find better tutorials of OOPS in php,please suggest that also.I is really appreciated.thanks man.

Comment: i need to improve my basic first..I didn't understand by provided link,sorry.Please refer the tutorial for biganners,i havn't knowledge of OOPS yet.

Comment: Actually I haven't used any tutorial like that, you ca just search on Google

Comment: no probs,Thanks man,you did great job..best of luck for your future. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code help you,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/airgle/navigation1/file_name$
RewriteRule ^$ http://localhost/navigation1/file_name [L,R=301]
```